# word problem about right-angle triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

An observer who is standing $47$ m from a building, measures the angle of elevation of the top of the building as $17°.$ If the observers eye is $167$ cm from the ground, what is the height of the building?

Comment: This isn't a word problem. This is a **picture problem**!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Here height of building is $AC$

In right angle triangle $\Delta ABC$
$$\dfrac {h}{47}=\tan 17^\circ\implies h=47\tan17^\circ$$
so total height of building is $(1.67+47\tan17^\circ)$ m $\approx16$m

Answer (score 2):

Let denote by $x$ the distance (elevation) from the obsever's eye to the top of building so
$$x=47\tan(17^°)\approx 14.36 m$$
so the height of the building is $h=x+1.67\approx 16 m$